# WPF Al poner ResizeMode="CanMinimize" oculta la barra de tareas de windwos

Tags: .net, wpf, material-design

tengo el siguiente problema, estoy haciendo una aplicación en WPF y me interesa que el usuario no pueda cambiarle el tamaño a la ventana, entonces en la definicion de la ventana cuando pongo ResizeMode="CanMinimize" me oculta la barra de tareas de windows y ocupa toda la pantalla, he colocado WindowState Maximized, Normal y nada que se acomoda, tambien he puesto todos los windowStyle y tampoco. espero me puedan ayudar
este es el xaml de mi ventana

```
<Window x:Class="HisMed.MainWindow"
    x:Name="MainWindowP"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HisMed"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
     xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    Title="Hismed" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" WindowState="Maximized" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

intentanta probando el siguiente codigo

primero determina cual es el tamaño del área de trabajo del monitor principal tanto para el ancho como para el alto
y segundo lo pones como valores minimos del windows para que no puedan minimizar menos al tamaño de su pantalla

```
public MainWindow()
{

   InitializeComponent();
   this.MinWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
   this.MinHeight = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
   this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
}
```

Comment: ok ya lo probare y estare comentando, gracias